# Deriving Key() from get_by_id()

Tags: python, google-app-engine, key

I have made user registration which includes (name, password, email, phone no) and now trying to include image too in Google App engine datastore. Everything is working fine just image uploading and resizing was troublesome. But, I have make it work now.

Basically there are three handlers

- First one for registration page handler (information testing and redirecting to userpage)

> """Get all requests from registration page and store in database"""
>
> ```
> userinfo.put()
> u_id = userinfo.key().id()
> ```
>
> """create cookie and hash where value is u_id"""
>
> `self.redirect(/userpage)`

- Second is userpage handler (which validate cookie created in registration handler, if hash cookie is valid then redirect to userpage else redirect to registration page again)

> ```
> user_id = Users.get_by_id(u_id)
> user_key = ?  # how can I get key of user_id
> ```
>
> `self.render("user.html", user =user_id.user, avatar = user_id.avatar)`

- Third is image handler

> ```
> class disp_image(webapp.RequestHandler):
>   def get(self):
>       key = self.request.get('key')
>       image = Users.get(key)
>       self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = "image/png"
>       return self.response.out.write(image.avatar)
> ```

**Template**

```
<img src="/disp?key={{avatar}}" />
```

**I have already solve the problem, revision was made to make it more clear for who have down-voted my question earlier.**

Comment: Downvote because of style... I'd like to read some more text, describing the topic/context of your question.

Comment: @thchand: It is really *not* cool to edit your question to turn it into an entirely new question. If you have a new question to ask, ask it in a new question.

Comment: @Adam Crossland- thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`user_key = user_id.key()`

But why is your head spinning? What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your problem is to understand, key, key_name and id? You have to read carefully the documentation of the class `db.Key`

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/keyclass

```
key = userinfo.key() # Returns an instance of the class `db.Key`
if key.id(): # That means the key use a numeric ID
  id = key.id()
else: # That means you can not have an ID in numeric and in string
  key_name = key.name() # That means the key use a string ID
```

As you can read on the doc, when you want to create an object db.Key you as to use the method `Key.from_path(kind, id_or_name, parent=none, namespace=None, **kwds)` this method uses as ID a string **or** a long.

> The id, specified as a string or long. It cannot be the number 0.